# value reset using .live after $ post values are hidden

Tags: jquery

I am using `.live` jQquery function to update something from a $post php script that opens a pop up on an input box.  The problem is the value of the text goes to input string but then dissapears when the pop up bar `fadesOut()`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function()  {
   $(".category").live("click", function(){
     varval= $(this).text();
     $("#inputString").val(varval);
   });
});
</script>
```

I would really appreciate some help on how I can make the value stay.

here is my HTML

```
<div>
<form id="searchform">
    <div>
        What are you looking for? <input type="text" size="30" value="" id="inputString" onkeyup="lookup(this.value);" />
    </div>
    <div id="suggestions"></div>
</form>
```

Here is the JS

```
function lookup(inputString) {
if(inputString.length == 0) {
    $('#suggestions').fadeOut(); // Hide the suggestions box
} else {
    $.post("rpc.php", {queryString: ""+inputString+""}, function(data) { // Do an AJAX call
        $('#suggestions').fadeIn(); // Show the suggestions box
        $('#suggestions').html(data); // Fill the suggestions box
    });
}
```

}

this calls a php file thats out putting the following

```
 <p id="searchresults">
  <?php


    while ($result = $query ->fetch_object()) {
                        if($result->liveSearchID != $catid) { // check if the category changed
                            echo '<a href="" class="category">'.$result->Keyword.'</a>';
                            $catid = $result->liveSearchID;
                        }

   ?></p>
```

OK here is a variation I tried that is still doing the same thing

```
$(document).delegate(".category", "click", function( event ) {
var varval= $(this).text();
 $("#inputString").val(varval);
});
```

I put a test link to my server on for you guys

PLEASE use pasta as the test text

```
visit http://122.160.94.46/autoSuggest1/
```

Comment: BTW I tried the on function but it did not work

Comment: Post your HTML, can't tell anything by this.

Comment: @mindmyweb: You can't just change `live` to `on` and expect it to work the same.  The syntax is different.

Comment: As a note, the `live` method [is deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/live/) in jQuery 1.7 and removed in 1.9. If you're having a lot of trouble getting it to work, you might want to use the new approach. Have you checked the JavaScript error console?

Comment: Something is obviously missing? If it dissapears when something fades out, where's the code for the fading out? And as noted in other comments, stop using live().

Comment: @tymeJV I have posted a test link for you.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the space?

```
varval= $(this).text();
```

change to

```
var val= $(this).text();
```

reworked for newer jQuery versions:

```
$(document).ready(function()  {
   $(document).on('click',".category", function(){
     var val= $(this).text();
     $("#inputString").val(val);
   });
});
```

Please try to find a lower level container on the `.category` rather than "document" to attach the event handerl to.

EDIT: based on your markup change posted, you likely need to prevent the default on the link click.  Try this optional segment:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#searchresults').on('click', ".category", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var val = $(this).text();
        $("#inputString").val(val);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Here is a working fiddle showing this, well working...http://jsfiddle.net/saYKy/

Comment: Actually it's referred to as `varval` in both cases, so as ugly as it looks, should work.

Comment: NOTE: if this does not resolve the issue, we will need more code, markup envolved - including the post code that modfies the page.

Comment: @tadman Yes, it does create that property on the document as is, but the 'on' should be better served here than the depricated `.live`

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss it says the syntax is wrong   ---SyntaxError: missing ; before statement
error source line:
[Break On This Error]  

$(document).on('click',".category") function(){

Comment: That should be `on('click', '.category', function() ...`

Comment: yep, fumble fingered the syntax rework - corrected it, should be ok, lots of assumptions here without more information from the OP.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss I have provided the full code plus a demo link at the top. Your code is working but the problem still eludes me. As soon as the value is entered into the input box it dissapears.

Comment: HUGE assumption here is you have valid markup and the `searchresults` id is unique on your page as the HTML specification requires.